# How to extend ClosedRange where Bound is generic

Tags: swift, generics, range, extend

For some additional functionality I’d like to extend `ClosedRange` where the Bounds are `Measurement`.

```swift
extension ClosedRange where Bound == Measurement
```

…obviously isn’t working as `Measurement` as a generic type requires an `<>` argument.

```swift
extension ClosedRange where Bound == Measurement<UnitType> // Cannot find type 'UnitType' in scope
```

Concatenating `where`s doesn’t seem to work either.

I am out of ideas.

The only thing I found to be working is:

```swift
extension ClosedRange where Bound == Measurement<UnitLength> {

    func unit() -> UnitLength {
        return lowerBound.unit
    }

}

let range = Measurement(value: 5, unit: UnitLength.meters)...Measurement(value: 15, unit: UnitLength.meters)
range.unit().symbol // m
```

But I don’t want to copy and paste this for all unit types. Isn’t this what generics are there for after all?

This comes close to what I want, doesn’t work though:

```swift
extension ClosedRange where Bound == Measurement<UnitType> { // Cannot find type 'UnitType' in scope

    func unit() -> UnitType { // Cannot find type 'UnitType' in scope
        return lowerBound.unit
    }

}

let range = Measurement(value: 5, unit: UnitLength.meters)...Measurement(value: 15, unit: UnitLength.meters)
range.unit
```

EDIT:

Thanks Dávid Pásztor for the answer. I would like to extend my question:

How can I add a function for `Measurement`s with `UnitType`s that inherit from `Dimension`?

```swift
extension ClosedRange {

    func convertedLowerBound<UnitType>(to unit: UnitType) -> Double where Bound == Measurement<UnitType> {
        lowerBound.converted(to: unit).value // Referencing instance method 'converted(to:)' on 'Measurement' requires that 'UnitType' inherit from 'Dimension'
    }

}

let range = Measurement(value: 5, unit: UnitLength.meters)...Measurement(value: 15, unit: UnitLength.meters)
range.convertedLowerBound(to: .centimeters)
```

```
Referencing instance method 'converted(to:)' on 'Measurement' requires that 'UnitType' inherit from 'Dimension'
```

Yes, I could just call `range.lowerBound.converted(to: .centimeters)`. The exact functionality I plan to implement doesn’t work like this though.

Comment: Why not simply `range.lowerBound.unit` ? I mean the `ClosedRange` has no unit type, the Bound does. Btw you would need also to implement `Range` as well

Comment: if you want to make it really generic `extension RangeExpression {` `func unit<T>() -> T where Bound == Measurement<T> {` `switch self {` `case let range as Range<Bound>: return range.lowerBound.unit` `case let range as ClosedRange<Bound>: return range.lowerBound.unit` `case let range as PartialRangeFrom<Bound>: return range.lowerBound.unit` `case let range as PartialRangeUpTo<Bound>: return range.upperBound.unit` `case let range as PartialRangeThrough<Bound>: return range.upperBound.unit` `default: fatalError()` `}` `}` `}`

Comment: Interesting, thx!

Comment: @LeoDabus Would there be a way to constrain `T` to `Dimension` in your example? Like `Bound == Measurement<T: Dimension>` or something? Or by adding `where T == Dimension` (both suggestions obviously don’t work).

Comment: `func unit<T>() -> T where Bound == Measurement<T>, T: Dimension {`

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the extension itself generic, however that's not yet supported by Swift. You can make the function itself generic though.

```
extension ClosedRange {
    func unit<UnitType>() -> UnitType where Bound == Measurement<UnitType> {
        lowerBound.unit
    }

    func convertedLowerBound<UnitType: Dimension>(to unit: UnitType) -> Double where Bound == Measurement<UnitType> {
        lowerBound.converted(to: unit).value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I added a followup question, would be great if you also had a solution for that ;)

Comment: @CelesteB check my updated answer. You simply need to add a generic type restriction of `Dimension` to `UnitType`.